# Any application for ubuntu similar to windows task manager !

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, task-manager

I am newbie in Ubuntu. I need application same as task manager works for Windows-Platform.

> I prefer if shortcut available. *Example:*  CTRL+ALT+DEL in Windows Task manager

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for the Gnome System Monitor

Find it under System -> Administration -> System Monitor

Use the "Keyboard Shortcuts" application to create a shortcut to the `gnome-system-monitor` command.

Comment: It works fine but is there any shortcut available for this as CTRL+ALT+DEL in Windows Task manager ?

Comment: You can add your own through the gnome preferences. Check out http://www.debian-administration.org/article/Creating_global_keyboard_shortcuts_in_GNOME

Comment: The use Keyboard Shortcuts, click Add, and "Task Manager" and put `gnome-system-monitor` in the command box, then assign Ctrl+Alt+Del to the newly created item.